# I'm trying to retrive values from a struct in MatNode C#

Tags: c#, matlab

I have a matlab file which have 2 fields.
version, struct.
version is a double value.
struct contains 20 rows in it.

I used MatNode to get the value from it.
Which gives only the first row values.

In debug, i Could see the non-public member dimensions as 20.

How can i get all the values from this matnode?

Comment: I think it would help if you included a short C# program that demonstrates what you did (see [mre]).

Comment: It is a two dimension array so try either x[][]  or x[,]